# Changing base field for sum of polynomials

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be a finite extension and $f_{1},\dotsc,f_{n}\in L[x_{1},\dotsc,x_{k}]$ be degree $d$ homogeneous polynomials. Is there a way to find homogenous degree $d’$ polynomials $g_{1},\dotsc,g_{n}\in L[x_{1},\dotsc,x_{k}]$ such that $f_{1}g_{1}+\dotsc f_{n}g_{n}\in \mathbb{Q}[x_{1},\dots,x_{k}]$ and $d’<d$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always. Take $k=3$, $n=2$, $f_1=\sqrt{2}x_1^2+x_2^2$, $f_2=x_3^2$.

Comment: @FredorPetrov if you knew $g_{1},\dotsc,g_{n}$ existed is there a way of finding them?

Comment: @M056 well, after all it is a linear over $\mathbb{Q}$ system of equations

Comment: @FredorPetrov How are you viewing this as a linear system of equations?

Comment: Choose a basis of $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, expand all coefficients in this basis and open the brackets.

Comment: @FredorPetrov Apologies for my stupidity: if $t=\text{number of degree}\ d$ monomials in $L[x_{1},\dotsc,x_{k}]$ then you have a vector space of dimension $t[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ which $f_{1},\dotsc,f_{n}$ lie in. I don’t get how this helps find $g_{1},\dotsc,g_{n}$ such that we get the desired property (unless maybe you want the sum to be 0).

Comment: Yes, and $g_i$'s lie in a similar space for $d'$, and the condition for $\sum f_ig_i$ having rational coefficients is a linear system